# ASP.NET MVC JSON get value with two Parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, onchange

I am trying to get value based on 2 parameters, below is my function where I added my 2 parameters in JSON stringify :

```js
function GetItemLocationOnHand(itemId, locationId) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        itemId: itemId,
        locationId: locationId
    });
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data,
        url: 'getItemInventory3',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#txtInventory3").val(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));
    
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error")
    
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my code in my controller to retrieve the data I want based on these two parameters :

```cs
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItemLocationOnHand(int itemId, int locationId)
{
    var itemLocQuantity = objDB.ItemLocationDatas.Single(items => items.ItemId == itemId && items.LocationId == locationId).Quantity;
    return Json(itemLocQuantity, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Upon calling this function via below on `change` code, I can't seem to get my data and is always returning the error.. If I only have 1 parameter, then no error encountered.

Please advise what went wrong when trying to pass 2 parameters.

```js
$("#LocationId").change(function () {
    var itemId = $("#ItemId").val();
    var locationId = $("#LocationId").val();

    GetItemLocationOnHand(itemId, locationId)
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` give you, just before the `$.ajax`

Comment: *always returning the error* ... what's the error?

Comment: ` url: 'getItemInventory3' ` ? what's the full url you want to call?

Comment: Below is what being returned in client side :
site1.dtempurl.com/Inventory/getItemInventory3?{"itemId":"11","locationId":"7"}                                 

below is the requested URL:
Requested URL: /Inventory/getItemInventory3

Comment: But your C# Action is called `GetItemLocationOnHand` not `getItemInventory3`.  Change your `error:` callback to include the error:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So, you want to send this `site1.dtempurl.com/Inventory/getItemInventory3?{"itemId":"11","locationId":"7"} ` instead of this `site1.dtempurl.com/Inventory/getItemInventory3?itemId=11&locationId=7` or `site1.dtempurl.com/Inventory/getItemInventory3?json={"itemId":"11","locationId":"7"}`?

Comment: Do you understand that when you have a GET request your params should be formatted as pair `paramname=value` ... in your case there's no paramname ... how do you get the query at the backend?

Comment: Remove stringify on your data - you just pass data as an object to $.ajax not as a string:  `var data = { itemId: itemId, locationId: locationId });`  (once you use the correct action name so you don't get a 404)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue! :) 
- added correct URL which is GetItemLocationOnHand
- removed Stringify and used var data = ({ itemId: itemId, locationId: locationId }); instead

Thank you @freedomn-m and Reflective for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See my example below. This works for me when doing ajax requests to a MVC controller with multiple params.

1. Below is my MVC controller action with multiple params.

   ```
    // GET
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string referenceID, int typeID, int supplierID, bool isArchived)
    {
        // Do CODE here
    }
   ```
2. Below is my Ajax request that I use to get or post. Depending on your needs. I use data type 'JSON' and format my data as a JSON object.

   ```
          var formData = {referenceID: 'Test', typeID: 3, supplierID: 2, isArchived: false};
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            url: getActionUrl, // url: domain/controller/action |or| domain/area/controller/action
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            headers: headers, // ignore if not needed. I use it for __RequestVerificationToken
            data: formData,
            success: function (data, status, xml) {
                // do something with the data
            },
            error: function (xml, status, error) {
                console.log(xml)
                // do something if there was an error
            },
            complete: function (xml, status) {
            }
        });
   ```

I think your issue might be that you are using 'JSON.stringify'. It could be interpreting your JSON string as a single parameter input and not two separate parameters.

Please see below snippets from documentation. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

- If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.
- The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

Comment: That's what I'm telling but why `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.
Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Same happens when you set `Content-type` of your response headers to `application/json` ... which is the right way to handle I believe

Comment: I also see the following in the documentation.
The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

Comment: `If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response`  so if response header content-type is set to JSON, it will be treated as JSON, if set ot `text/html` in case you don't call the right location per instance or you have a html default error handler, it will be treated as HTML, so it won't be parsed as JSON and you won't have an error, an you may check your response parsing it as HTML ...

Comment: Do you understand the difference and why setting response headers content-type is better than setting dataType on your request? It's useful only when you check `accept` in request header in case you may return different kind of responses i.e. xml, son, text depending on `accept` ... but that's not the usual case.

Comment: @Reflective, thanks for sharing that knowledge. I'll go read up on it some more. So far from what you've said, I agree. It does seem more appropriate to use the Content-type of your response headers. You're welcome to edit the above answer to your standard.

Comment: You are welcome! My idea is not the tell you are doing it wrong, I'm sure the way you do  will work, but to it could be better. That's what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by doing the following :

- added correct URL which is GetItemLocationOnHand
- removed Stringify and used var data = ({ itemId: itemId, locationId:
  locationId });

thanks a lot to Freedom and Reflective and others for your comments!

```
 function GetItemLocationOnHand(itemId, locationId) {
        var data = ({ itemId: itemId, locationId: locationId });


        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: data,
            url: 'getItemLocationOnHand',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#txtInventory3").val(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error")

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to avoid some misunderstanding how AJAX GET works and setting some parameters which you don't have to set (i.e. you are still not so deep into jQuery AJAX) you may use the shortcut they also implemented i.e. `$.get` so your request will look as simple as that and you can't get wrong as it will use the proper defaults for GET. If you want the response to be treated as JSON, just set `Content-type` of your response headers (from backed) to `application/json`. This will be checked by jQuery AJAX response handler and it will parse the incoming data as JSON.

```js
    var data = {itemId: 1, locationId: 2 };
    $.get('GetItemLocationOnHand', data, function (data) {
      $("#txtInventory3").val(parseFloat(data).toFixed(2));    
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert(`Error = ${jqXHR.status} ${textStatus}`);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```